# how can i use keyboard hook in mfc application (C++ in Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

how can i use keyboard hook in mfc application?
i try this

```
typedef struct tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT {
    DWORD   vkCode;
    DWORD   scanCode;
    DWORD   flags;
    DWORD   time;
    DWORD   dwExtraInfo;
} KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, FAR *LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, *PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeybdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == 0x0100)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKey = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << " ";
    }
    CallNextHookEx(KbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CUSBDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    cout << "Successfully Loaded !!!" << endl;
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);

    HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    KbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeybdProc, hInstance, 0);

    return TRUE;
}
```

it priting "Successfully Loaded !!!" but keybdproc not working.
someone can help me?

Comment: Check `GetLastError`after `SetWindowsHookEx` for more informations.

Comment: why would you want to use a keyboard hook on your own application?  Just respond to the key events that your application receives from Windows.

Comment: @MikeNakis Keyboard hooks are Windows-wide, so you can receive the key events from other active applications (e.g. Browser).

Comment: @shadowlif: more accurately, a keyboard hook receives key events before any apps receive them. You can do the same thing with the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx), which is preferable over a keyboard hook, especially if you already have an `HWND` to receive the events with.

Comment: @kimjaehui: the `lParam` value contains a valid pointer only when the `nCode` value is 0, but you are not checking for that. And don't use magic numbers in your code, use meaningful defines instead: `if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN))`. And you shouldn't be defining `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` manually, it is already defined in `winuser.h` for you.